# Msal4j browser login window never opens

Tags: java, javafx, azure-ad-msal

Java Version - OpenJDK 17
OS - Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa

I'm trying to implement interactive token acquisition from a JavaFX desktop app and running into some trouble getting the browser window to open in order to login.

[MRE](https://github.com/Jeremy-Code-F/Msal4JMre) (just make sure to update PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID in HelloApplication.java to a valid client id)

In the start function in HelloApplication.java I've setup [this example in the docs](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Acquiring-Token-Interactively) in my Controller's constructor

```
public HelloController() throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {
    PublicClientApplication publicClientApplication =
        PublicClientApplication
        .builder(CLIENT_ID)
        .authority(AUTHORITY)
        .build();

    InteractiveRequestParameters parameters = InteractiveRequestParameters
        .builder(new URI("http://localhost"))
        .scopes(scope)
        .build();

    IAuthenticationResult result = publicClientApplication.acquireToken(parameters).join();
}
```

I would expect that a browser window would open that I could then login with my MS credentials, what actually happens is it never opens a browser window and the .join() on the CompletableFuture never returns.

Is there anything else that needs to be setup in order to get the browser window to open?

Comment: You might want file request to Microsoft that they provide a tutorial or complete executable code example in git on using their API and services from a JavaFX application.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know the Microsoft lib at all, but from looking at the Java sample in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token?tabs=java), it says the join() method will:

> Try to acquire a token interactively with system browser.
>
> If successful, you should see the token and account information printed out to console.

So your current code would freeze your app until that occurs as you are waiting on the JavaFX thread.

You should acquire the token in a JavaFX `Task` (research JavaFX concurrency) or some other means (which I don’t know at the moment).

Perhaps you also want to [customize the open browser action](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Acquiring-Token-Interactively#customizing-the-experience) using either

1. The JavaFX api `HostServices.show()` to show the page in an external web browser

   OR
2. Load the content into a WebView to embed it in your app.

Comment: Thanks, so acquireToken returns a CompletableFuture, if I remove the .join from it everything works, browser opens and I can authenticate, guess it's some weird thing with joining specifically on the gui thread. 
CompletableFuture task = app.acquireToken(parameters);
I was thinking the join would block until the browser authentication process finished then the app would startup as normal.
tldr; concurrency is the answer